# .html form info failing to submit to email via .php

Tags: php, html, forms, html-email

I have created an html form that is designed to do two things - submit form information to a specified email address and redirect users to another page on the site. I created a .php form to manage these actions. The form successfully redirects and an email is sent. However, the email has the correct destination, subject, and message, but fails to pull in the information the user submitted to the form - i.e. name, address, email, etc.

I am completely new to web development, but would appreciate any insight you can provide. Thank you!

HTML:

```
<section>
   <div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12"><form name="Whitepaper 
Request form" method="POST" action="Info-Request.php" class="text-center">

<input name="First_Name" type="text" required class="contact-field-sm" 
id="fname" placeholder="First Name">

<input name="Last_Name" type="text" required class="contact-field-sm" 
id="lname" placeholder="Last Name"><br><br>

<input name="Address" type="text" class="contact-field-sm" id="address" 
placeholder="Address">

<input name="City" type="text" class="contact-field-sm" id="city" 
placeholder="City"><br><br>

<input name="State" type="text" class="contact-field-sm" id="state" 
placeholder="State">

<input name="Zip" type="text" class="contact-field-sm" id="zip" 
placeholder="Zip"><br><br>

<input name="Phone" type="tel" class="contact-field-sm" id="phone" 
placeholder="Phone">

<input name="Email" type="email" class="contact-field-sm" id="email" 
placeholder="Email"><br><br>

<input name="Company" type="text" required class="contact-field-sm" 
id="company" placeholder="Company">

<input name="Title" type="text" required class="contact-field-sm" id="title" 
placeholder="Title"><br><br>

<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))

$to = "email@example.com";
$from = 'Whitepaper Request Form';
$email_subject = " ";
$email_message = "Results from Whitepaper Request Form:\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
     }

 $First_Name = $_POST['First_Name'];
 $Last_Name = $_POST['Last_Name'];

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($First_Name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($Last_Name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($Address)."\n";
    $email_message .= "City: ".clean_string($City)."\n";
    $email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($State)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Zip: ".clean_string($Zip)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($Phone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($Email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Company: ".clean_string($Company)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Title: ".clean_string($Title)."\n";

 mail($to,$from,$email_subject,$email_message);
 header('Location: Example_Retro_WhtP.pdf');
 ?>
```

[EDITED] PHP:

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $to = 'example@example.com';
 $subject = 'Whitepaper Request Form';
 $email_message = 'Results from Whitepaper Request Form:\n\n';
 $headers = 'From: example@example.com';

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
      }

   $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($_POST['First_Name'])."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($Last_Name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($Address)."\n";
    $email_message .= "City: ".clean_string($City)."\n";
    $email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($State)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Zip: ".clean_string($Zip)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($Phone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($Email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Company: ".clean_string($Company)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Title: ".clean_string($Title)."\n";

 mail($to,$subject,$email_message,$headers);
 header('Location: Example_Retro_WhtP.pdf');
     exit;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: The first and last name should be coming through but none of the other info since you never reference the POST variables. E.g. `$_POST['Email']`

Comment: The first and last names as POST variables didn't work, either.

Comment: You're already doing the proper thing with the first and last names (only) all your other form variables aren't wrapped in `$_POST['']`. Try adding a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump()` to your PHP script to see what's coming across from your form.

Comment: @j08691, I'm not sure what you mean by `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Add that line to your PHP script after `<?php`

Comment: @j08691 I'm not sure what that's supposed to do, but I didn't get any alternative results in the email

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified. Comment out the email and redirect lines so you can see the output

Comment: I'm so sorry; I'm still not understanding. I tried this, which didn't work, either: `$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($_POST['First_Name'])."\n";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (main) problem is with the arguments used in the following, and there are a few other issues.

```
mail($to,$from,$email_subject,$email_message);
```

The syntax for PHP [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) is this and in the following order:

- $to = "To the recipient".
- $subject = "The mail's subject".
- $email_message = "The mail content".
- $headers = "That's where you put the From: email@example.com". (which need to be added and is not present).

As per the manual's syntax:

> bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Follow that syntax and the mail will contain everything that was used to send it out with.

Note: You will need to add the POST arrays that are missing for the other inputs.

However, you state that the email gets sent. In seeing the following condition:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
```

That is the reason why your code does send out the mail because there is no submit input bearing that name, therefore it's never "set".

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Should read as:

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

and do use proper bracing techniques.

I.e.: note, I removed the `!` operator, which means "not":

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    // run your code in here to be executed

}
```

while adding an `else{...}` condition.

Also check for errors with PHP's error reporting:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Adding an `exit;` after the header won't hurt also, it's even recommended to prevent further execution (should you have more code below it).

It's also best to check for empty fields using `empty()` and `isset()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your suggestions made a lot of sense. Here is my updated code. I am getting redirect just fine to the other page, but am no longer receiving an email in my inbox.

Comment: @care_apog please don't drop code in comments. I've given you the basics of how it's done. Your header btw is failing, no idea why you want to use a `.pdf` file as a redirection.

Comment: I need users to fill out a form before being allowed to access the .pdf document. Thanks again for your help; very appreciated.